# Magento 2.3.2 Invalid entity_type specified: Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, custom-field, extension-attributes

I have created a custom **select** field on the checkout address form. a field is displayed fine but when clicking on next button getting error `"Invalid entity_type specified: Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface on checkout"`

Check below the screen-shot.
[image]

I have followed the below links but no luck.

- [Add a new field in address form](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)
- [How To Add Custom Field At Checkout Address Form In Magento 2](https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-field-checkout-address-form-magento2/)
- [How to add new fields in address form](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-new-fields-address-form-magento-2.html)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What's template and elementTmpl in config section of component in your code?

Comment: 'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select'

Comment: what about extension_attributes.xml?

Comment: Already defined `extension_attribute.xml`  i have followed this all step https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html